# Is there a way to return all updated rows in JOOQ batch update

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

i'm trying to perform batch update query with returning of all affected rows. Maybe someone could help

```
fun updateStatuses(writeOffRequestsIds: Collection<UUID>, status: WriteOffRequestStatus): List<WriteOffRequest> {
    val records = writeOffRequestsIds.map { id ->
        db.update(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST)
            .set(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.STATUS, status)
            .set(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.UPDATED_AT, LocalDateTime.now())
            .where(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.ID.eq(id))
            .returning()
    }
//doesnt compile here
*return db.batchUpdate(*records.toTypedArray()).fetchInto(WriteOffRequest::class.java)
*}
```

I've tried several different approaches. created collection of UpdateableRecord etc. but it just doesnt work anyway

Answer (score 0):

As of jOOQ 3.18, there's a pending feature request to return generated IDs from batch `INSERT` statements, which some JDBC drivers (but only a few) support natively:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3327

I don't have high hopes of the same being possible for `UPDATE` statements. But why not just bulk update the entire data set? E.g.:

```kotlin
Table<*> s = sourceData.`as`("s");
```

You can construct `sourceData` using [`DSL.values()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#values(org.jooq.Row1...)), jOOQ's support for the [`VALUES` constructor operator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values/), for example:

```kotlin
Table<*> s = values(writeOffRequestsIds.map { id -> 
    row(id, status)
}).`as`("s", "id", "status")
```

And then:

```kotlin
ctx.update(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST)
   .set(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.STATUS, s.field(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.STATUS)))
   .set(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.UPDATED_AT, LocalDateTime.now())
   .from(s)
   .where(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.ID.eq(s.field(WRITE_OFF_REQUEST.ID)))
   .returning()
   .fetch();
```

This will work only in some dialects that can support this natively, or emulate it in some way, e.g. (as of jOOQ 3.18) in:

- CockroachDB
- Db2
- Firebird
- H2
- MariaDB
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- SQL Server
- YugabyteDB

Comment: not sure how to use DSL.values(). As i understand you propose select updatable records at first and then use result of such select in update statement? Then it's become quite similar as just to do update and select afterwards and i tried to avoid it

Comment: @DaniilSpirin: No, I mean use `DSL.values()`, just like you would use that operator in SQL. See the udpated answer and https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values/

Comment: Got type mismatch when attempting to use result of row() method into values():
Type mismatch.
Required:
RowN!
Found:
List<Row2<UUID!, WriteOffRequestStatus!>

Comment: @DaniilSpirin: I can answer a new question with more details